# Office 365 rule not working for connected account

Tags: office365

I create a rule for replying to all incoming emails in Office365.

I have a 'connected account' (this is an external email account that Office365 pulls from using POP3).

If I test sending emails to my 'native' Office365 email address the rule works. However, if I send testing emails to the 'connected account' email address the rule doesn't work. It seems that the rule ignore emails coming from the connected account.

The issue that I am to resolve is to get Out Of Office Assistant responses to emails sent to the 'connected account'. Please note that the standard Out of Office option ignores emails from the connected account.

Please advise.

Comment: Please provide a drawing of what you are trying to describe.

Comment: Ramhound: thanks for your interest. I included more details in the question - as for creating a drawing: I do not think that's necessary (or would help). Thanks.

Comment: I have exact same problem in the outlook.com after the upgrade recently. Was on a phone for an hour with a guy from MS, and all I got was going through my mailbox and 'Microsoft is working on this'. Working on this my ass, problem from 2 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

### Solved!

I previously had created 2 *working* rules in Outlook 2013, both of which deleted incoming emails based on specific words in the subject; after upgrading to Outlook 2016, 1 rule quit working.

I compared the previously-working rule to the rule that still worked.

Under *Select condition(s)*, both had check-marks by 'with specific words in the subject'; only the words were different.

Under *Select action(s)*, 'delete it' was checked in both rules, however, the non-working rule also had 'mark it as read' checked; I assumed the latter had nothing to do with why this rule no-longer worked.

After searching the web and trying everything including deleting and re-creating the non-working rule umpteen times, my 1st *'solution'* was to add the non-working rule's subject-area words to the working rule's list of subject-area words; which worked immediately.

A few days ago whilst perusing the **Deleted Items** folder prior to emptying it, I noticed a ton of emails with bold headers - I.E. marked unread - that had been deleted by the working rule, and so I edited the working rule, adding a check-mark under *Select action(s)* beside 'mark it as read'.

When I fired-up Outlook 2016 the following morning, the (previously) still-working rule no longer worked (although it successfully worked when I manually ran it).

Though I couldn't believe the previous day's change was the culprit behind the rule's failure, I nevertheless un-checked 'mark it as read' in the *Rules Wizard* under *Select action(s)*, then I saved my change and reopened Outlook.

The rule once again worked and continues to run every day as expected. After un-selecting 'mark it as read' on the other rule which had stopped working, it too ran again without failure. I don't know why deselecting the 'mark it as read' action solved my problem, I'm just glad it's fixed.